# How to hide the Soft Keyboard when Enter key is pressed on WindowsPhone / Windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-8.1

I want to hide the Soft Keyboard when enter/return key is pressed from editing a TextBox. This is what I have so far in c#:

```
private void SearchBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        if(e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
        {
            this.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic); // sending focus to Page to hide keyboard
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this work? If not, what happens? Please explain further.

Comment: You have solved it by disabling and re-enabling the textBox. The switch focus way I was trying doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try shortly disabling and then enabling the TextBox.

```
if(e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
{
    textBox.IsEnabled = false;
    textBox.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: How can this dumb thing can be possibly the w8.1 solution. Keyboard.hide or something like that can't exist ?

Comment: This solution only works if there is another control in the visual tree with `IsTabStop` set to `True`. Otherwise, the TextBox will regain focus and the virtual keyboard will stay on screen.

Answer (score 5):

```
private void BobbinRunningLength_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
        {
            this.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
        }
    }
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Correct solution for UWP

Answer (score 4):

Try this..

```
private void SearchBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{        
    if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        this.Focus();
    }
}
```

This should work.

Answer (score 4):

Enabling and disabling the TextBox did not work for me.

I'm using this for a Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime app:

```
private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
  {
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().CoreWindow.IsInputEnabled = false;
    Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.GetCurrentView().CoreWindow.IsInputEnabled = true;                
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has already been answered but I want to share my solution, I had an issue using virtual pages (grids with Visible/Collapsed) within a XAML page, when the soft keyboard was present and the page changed the soft keyboard was not automatically hidden, apparently because the parent of the focused control was collapsed, strange and undocumented behavior. My solution was to set the focus on an element of the next page to be shown, so the OS understand it and hide the soft keyboard:

```
xamlButton.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
selectPage(1);
```

Where selectPage(int); sets visible or collapsed property of the page by its index.

Setting the focus to a button worked well, since buttons don't have a keyboard input.